# ng-pick-datetime datepicker format

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I am using angular in that in that used `ng-pick-datetime` npm. When I trying to modify the format after select date (dd/MM/yyyy) but I got (MM/dd/yyyy) only. I do not know how to do.

Screenshot for more clarification about my question:

[image]

**HTML**

```
<input
    [owlDateTime]="dt1"
    [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt1"
    placeholder="Wedding Anniversary"
    formControlName="wedding"
    class="form-control"
    onkeydown="return false"
    id="text-input"
    name="wedding"
    max="{{ maxDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd' }}"
  />
  <owl-date-time #dt1 [pickerType]="'calendar'"></owl-date-time>
```

I need the result like this (dd/MM/yyyy).
Advanced thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Inject a object to your component with the date format that you need.

More info:  https://daniel-projects.firebaseapp.com/owlng/date-time-picker#implementation-format

```
import { DateTimeAdapter, OWL_DATE_TIME_FORMATS, OWL_DATE_TIME_LOCALE } from 'ng-pick-datetime';
import { MomentDateTimeAdapter } from 'ng-pick-datetime-moment';

export const MY_CUSTOM_FORMATS = {
  parseInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
  fullPickerInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm a',
  datePickerInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
  timePickerInput: 'hh:mm a',
  monthYearLabel: 'MMM-YYYY',
  dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
  monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM-YYYY'
};

@Component({
  selector: 'time-series',
  templateUrl: './time-series.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./time-series.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    { provide: DateTimeAdapter, useClass: MomentDateTimeAdapter, deps: [OWL_DATE_TIME_LOCALE] },
    { provide: OWL_DATE_TIME_FORMATS, useValue: MY_CUSTOM_FORMATS }
  ]
})
@Injectable()
export class TimeSeriesComponent {
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use picker with MomentJS
Here is an example to use OwlMomentDateTimeModule with different date-time formats: (Beware that OwlMomentDateTimeModule requires MomentJS)

> npm Install:

```
npm install ng-pick-datetime-moment moment --save;
```

Code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { OwlDateTimeModule, OWL_DATE_TIME_FORMATS} from 'ng-pick-datetime';
import { OwlMomentDateTimeModule } from 'ng-pick-datetime-moment';

// See the Moment.js docs for the meaning of these formats:
// https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/
export const MY_MOMENT_FORMATS = {
    parseInput: 'l LT',
    fullPickerInput: 'l LT',
    datePickerInput: 'l',
    timePickerInput: 'LT',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
};

@NgModule({
    imports: [OwlDateTimeModule, OwlMomentDateTimeModule],
    providers: [
        {provide: OWL_DATE_TIME_FORMATS, useValue: MY_MOMENT_FORMATS},
    ],
})
export class AppExampleModule {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly working me just now read document. Add below code in module

```
providers: [
    ClientService,
    DatePipe, 
    {provide: OWL_DATE_TIME_LOCALE, useValue: 'in'}
]
```

Comment: Cannot find name 'OWL_DATE_TIME_LOCALE

Answer (score 0):

update app.module

```
providers:[
{provide: OWL_DATE_TIME_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-GB'}
]
```